# Javascript function in /url page not working after using history.push(/url) onlick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my js function to hide/show login password, but when i redirect to login page from another page using history.push(/login) the function doesn't work. And when putting (/login) in the href in the  tag, it works. How can i fix this? Thank you.
Note: I dont want refresh my website so i dont want to use href or forceRefresh.

```js
var showPassword = function () {
  $('.show-pass').click(function (e) {
    var grand = $(this).parent();
    var type = $("#show-password", $(grand)).attr('type');
    switch (type) {
      case 'password':
        {
          $("#show-password", $(grand)).attr('type', 'text');
          $(".icon-invisible", $(grand)).removeClass('icon-invisible').addClass('icon-visible');
          return;
        }
      case 'text':
        {
          $("#show-password", $(grand)).attr('type', 'password');
          $(".icon-visible", $(grand)).removeClass('icon-visible').addClass('icon-invisible');
          return;
        }
    }
  });
};
```

a part of my router containing /login

```html
<Route  path="/login" component={SignIn}/>
```

this is my input password:

```html
<div className="form-group is-password">
  <input onChange={this.onPasswordChange} className="c-placeholder-login form-control" type="password" placeholder="Mật khẩu" tabIndex={2} id="show-password" />

  <button className="c-login__pass show-pass" style={{backgroundColor: "transparent"}}> <i className="icon-invisible" /></button>
</div>
```

Comment: history.push is a function that ONLY modify the url, without changing the real page path. You should use "window.location.href" to modify the path. Why don't you want to use href?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios bc it load all my website, and  i dont want to this.

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios i want my website working like FB web, only push the url without reload

Answer (score 0):

router properly and also wrapping the index.js file around the BrowserRouter like this = `<BrowserRouter> <App.js /> </BrowserRouter>`

Comment: should i put the <route> inside <app.js> or outside it?

Comment: you should put it in the index.js js file where u render the app component. And also did you import useHistory hook and initialise it?